# PHP MySQL Call Procedure and move on

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a php script I run on my staging machine that processes an xml file into my database then calls some MySQL procedures that are used to clean up the data with a bunch of queries.

I have some procedures that are getting huge and take a few hours to run (which is why it is done in staging).

Is there a way to have PHP call those procedures without waiting for a result to move onto the rest of the script?

Comment: different approaches are possible. Are you using a web interface to call each php script or is it done by command line?

Comment: I call the script via web interface so I can input some variables.

Comment: have you tried `explain` on those queries? Could the solution be as simple as adding some indexes? See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html

Comment: @Greg the procedures take about 3-5 hours to process, it is not an index issue, it is a processing volume "issue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't support concurrency in core. But you can simulate a similar behaviour with the following methods.

**1. fsockopen() and ignore_user_abort('1')**

You can create a socket connection to another script which runs then in background. Please see the following two scripts. The main script creates a socket connection to the sub script and closes it immediately. The sub script runs until all tasks are finished. This is because of the ini value "ignore_user_abort" is set to 1.

main.php

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
$host = 'localhost';
$target = '/sub.php';
$fp = fsockopen($host, 80);
$request  = "GET $target HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$request .= "Host: $host\r\n";
$request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $request);
fclose($fp);
file_put_contents("main", "Script runs " . (microtime(true) - $start) . " seconds");
```

sub.php

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
ignore_user_abort("1");
sleep(5);
file_put_contents("sub", "Script runs " . (microtime(true) - $start) . " seconds");
```

---

**2. Start a script over the command line in background**

You can start a script over the unix/linux or windows command line in background. The following example is for the unix/linux command line. To start the script over the windows command line see the following comment on the PHP.net site. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#110131

main.php

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
pclose(popen("/usr/bin/php "  . __DIR__ . "/sub.php " . __DIR__ . "//sub.log 2>&1 &", 'r'));
file_put_contents("main", "Script runs " . (microtime(true) - $start) . " seconds");
```

sub.php

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
sleep(5);
file_put_contents("sub", "Script runs " . (microtime(true) - $start) . " seconds");
```

---

**The following extension provides real concurrency in PHP:**

> pthreads is an Object Orientated API that allows user-land multi-threading in PHP. It includes all the tools you need to create multi-threaded applications targeted at the Web or the Console. PHP applications can create, read, write, execute and synchronize with Threads, Workers and Stackables.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a web interface, there's a possibility.
You could try to implement the following logic

1. One php script per "long mysql function"
2. Use AJAX to process each php script, so you can start any at the same time if you want. The server will parallelise the load.

Tell me what you think.

Comment: I like the idea, I was hoping for something a little simpler to implement.

Comment: this is extremly simple. Ajax fits in 10 lines of javascript. If you're lazy you can even copy paste :-)

Comment: I have not done much with Ajax or javascript for that matter, so even if it is simple, there is the learning curve for me I was hoping to skip. Do you have a an example you would recommend to speed up my learning curve?

Comment: this one seems concise enough: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php